# Does GpsSatellite.hasAlmanac() ever return true?

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I've done some testing of the method `GpsSatellite.hasAlmanac()`, which should return true if the GPS engine has almanac data for that satellite. It seems that `hasAlmanac()` always returns false (at least on my device: Samsung Galaxy Nexus). In fact, even though `usedInFix()` returns true, `hasAlmanac()` returns false. If you know something about how GPS receivers work, then you'll understand that this is an impossible combination...

Does anyone have better results?

Answer (score 1):

> A related problem has been fixed in 4.1.1:
>   The extra bundle obtained by getExtras() on a location 
>   for a GPS provider in onLocationChanged() callback was empty in 4.0.4 ---
>   in 4.1.1 it now contains the number of satellites that the GPS solution is based on ---
>   extracted using .getInt("satellites") --- as it should. Thank you!

taken from here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30569
So it should be fixed in android 4.1.1, if I am reading it correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using 4.2, so I don't think the problem is really fixed. Also, I think that the comment to the issue is only saying that a *related* problem has been fixed. It's not really clear whether this also solved the original problem. Are you able to confirm on an actual device whether the problem has been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

From my GPS knowledge `hasAlmanac()` must be true if the chip delivers a valid position.
At least is this valid for GPS Satellites.
Imagine a chip which supports GPS and GLONASS, then it´s theoretically possible that you have only a GPS almanac (an almanac is ever valid for all GPS Satellites) but no GLONASS almanac. 
But practically i would expect that hasAlmanac() is ever true for both GPS and GLONASS

There is another theoretic situation:
If you could set the almanac explictly, and the chip detects that the almanac is oudated, then there could be some seconds without almanac.

Or if your device was disbled for some month, and on boot inside a building you query the hasAlmanac(), then it could be false too. (It never received an almanac)

A almanc is valid for longer time, because it represents only the rough satellite epheremides.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't really answer my question. I agree that hasAlmanac() *should* return true in any case where I have a valid position. I am quite positive my device has an updated almanac because I used the app GPS Status and Toolbox to force a fresh download of the almanac.

Comment: Sorry did not saw your last sentence.